# Passing HTML form value to javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a page with one text box and a button when the button is clicked it sends the value to javascript and then writes stuff. I have spent quite some time looking and I can't see what I'm doing wrong. Here is both the script and page.

HTML:

```
    <!doctype html>
      <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>RDP</title>
       <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" 
             href = "css/style.css">
    </head>

    <body>  
        <div class='center'>
          <div class='header'>
              <h1>Home</h1>
          <h2></h2>
        </div>
          <div class='sidebar'>
            <ul>
                <li><a href='index.html'>Home</a></li>
                <li><a href='divevideo.html'>Video</a></li>
                <li>Dive Calculator</li>
            <li><a href='images.html'>Images</a></li>
         </ul>
      </div>
        <div class='main'>
         <p><form>Depth:<input name="Depth" type="text" id="Depth"value="35" size="3" maxlength="3">
            <input name="Calculate" type="button" id="calculate" onClick="DepthEntered()"     value="Calculate"></form></p>
         <p id='divetimes'></p>
         <script src="jsfiles/nodecom.js"></script>
      </div>
      <div class='footer'>
      </div>
    </div>
    </body>

   </html>
```

Javascript:

```
// JavaScript Document
function DepthEntered()
{
    var depth = document.getElementById("Depth").value;
    var nodetime;
    var sstime;

    //depth = window.prompt('What was your depth?')

    //depth = 62 //temperary test variable. remove to return to dynamic.

    if( depth >= 35 )
    {
        nodetime = 205
        sstime = 152
    }
    if( depth > 35 && depth >= 40 )
    {
        nodetime = 140
        sstime = 111
    }
    if( depth > 40 && depth >= 50 )
    {
        nodetime = 80
        sstime = 67
    }
    if( depth > 50 && depth >= 60 )
    {
        nodetime = 55
        sstime = 49
    }
    if( depth > 60 && depth >= 70 )
    {
        nodetime = 40
        sstime = 35
    }
    if( depth > 70 && depth >= 80 )
    {
        nodetime = 30
        sstime = 26
    }
    if( depth > 90 && depth >= 100 )
    {
        nodetime = 25
        sstime = 22
    }
    if( depth > 100 && depth >= 110 )
    {
        nodetime = 20
        sstime = 0
    }
    if( depth > 110 && depth >= 120 )
    {
        nodetime = 16
        sstime = 0
    }
    if( depth > 120 && depth >= 130 )
    {
        nodetime = 10
        sstime = 0
    }
    if( depth > 130 && depth >= 140 )
    {
        nodetime = 8
        sstime = 0
    }
    if( depth > 140 )
    {
        document.getElementById("divetimes").innerHTML = ('<p>There is no safe no decompression time for this depth.</p>');
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("divetimes").innerHTML = ('<p>At that depth your no decompression limit is <em class = myclass2>' + nodetime + '</em> minutes. You need to make a saftey if your down at least <em class = myclass3>' + sstime + '</em> minutes.</p>'); 
    };
}
```

Also how can I make it so only numbers can be entered?

Comment: You should start by looking into switches and objects as maps in javascript, and replace those if's with something a little nicer !

Comment: What is .value returning at present?

Comment: Also, to make your life easier, delete or comment out evertything except the bit that's not working.  Then, when that bit works you can all all the complex stuff.  It'll make you like easier!

Comment: You have an error in your HTML. The input tag is not closed.

Comment: Finally, Chrome and Firefox have powerful debugging tool built in, you can access them by pressing F12.  How a read up on them and you might save yourself hours in return.

Comment: Like Banksy said: your js ist defined after you want to use it. So the Function of the button is not find and it doesn't work!

Comment: adeneo I would love an easier way to do this but I am doing this for an IT class in school and I dont know what those things are yet. BanksySan it worked fine when i defined depth with a prompt. And I checked the debugging tool says nothing. Mic i dont understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With HTML5, giving input type='number' makes sure that the type of input entered is a number only. Adding a 'required at the end of the input tag would make sure that the user enters a number before submitting. works in most of the browsers. i.e.

<input name="Depth" type="number" id="Depth"value="35" size="3" maxlength="3" required>

plus to make it work, you can try parsing it to an integer in the javascript.
var d= parseInt(depth);

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: Thanks this answered my question! It was the parseInt part that sliped my mind.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your JavaScript is below your HTML, so `DepthEntered()` is defined in the window scope. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BrKJX/1/. Your code works as is!

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(document).on('keydown', '.numberOnly', function(e) {
        if(!((e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode <= 57) || (e.keyCode >= 97 && e.keyCode <= 106) || e.keyCode == 8)) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kelunik/ev3ec/3/)

Comment: But now you can't use the backspace.

Comment: I can't press backspace. also can't enter number from NUMLOCK section.

Comment: Added backspace and numblock support